# How can I dump Lua code to a format file?

Tags: luatex, lua, format-files

From this format:

```
%% testformat.ini
\input plain
\directlua {tex.enableprimitives('', tex.extraprimitives())}
\directlua {
testFunction = function ()
   tex.print("This was print by Lua's testFunction.\par")
end
}
%% \directlua {testFunction()}
%% \bye
\dump
```

I create a testformat.fmt with `$ luatex -ini testformat.ini`, but when trying to use it with the following test file:

```
%% test-testformat.tex
\directlua{testFunction()}
\bye
```

the globaly defined function testFunction is lost:

```
$ luatex -fmt testFormat.fmt test-testformat.tex 
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011120612 
(./test-testformat.tex
! LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: attempt to call global 'testFunction' (a nil va
lue)
stack traceback:
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
l.2 \directlua{testFunction()}

?
```

Should I do another trick in Lua or it simply can't be dumped and I must use something like `\everyjob{\directlua{dofile("testformat.lua")}}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the LaTeX3 `l3bootstrap` module, we wanted to enable the equivalent of `\pdfstrcmp` using Lua code for LuaTeX. To build that into a format, we wanted to avoid having to read a `.lua` file each run. Taco Hoekwater suggested the use of `lua.bytecode`. We use this as:

```
\directlua
  {
    lua.bytecode[1] = function ()
      function strcmp (A, B)
        if A == B then
          tex.write("0")
        elseif A < B then
          tex.write("-1")
        else
          tex.write("1")
        end
      end
    end
    lua.bytecode[1]()
  }
\everyjob\expandafter
  {\the\everyjob\directlua{lua.bytecode[1]()}}
```

*i.e.* you have to save the bytecode and use the `\everyjob` TeX primitive to active it for each run. (I've modified slightly from the version in the `.dtx` as there are other details there which are not relevant to this question.)

---

For reference, you would access the above using something like

```
\long\def\pdfstrcmp#1#2{%
     \directlua{strcmp("\luaescapestring{#1}","\luaescapestring{#2}" )}%
}
```

(The `pdfstrcmds` package calls this `\pdf@strcmp`, as it requires an additional expansion compared to the primitive and so is 'safest' given a different name. In the LaTeX3 load code, that's not a worry as we don't directly expose this, so we take a slightly different approach.)

Comment: I've answered in the absence of one from a LuaTeX expert: hopefully one will swing by sooner or later!

Comment: Probably `\everyjob\expandafter{\the\expandafter\everyjob\directlua{...}}` so not to clobber the current value of `\everyjob`

Comment: @egreg OK: I'm taking this from format-mode code, where I know at the point of use the status of `\everyjob` :-)

Comment: You missed an `\expandafter` if you want to also expand `\directlua`

Comment: @egreg No, I don't want to expand the `\directlua` (or at least that's not what we do in `l3bootstrap`)

Comment: @egreg expanding the `\directlua` would be the same as putting it outside the `\everyjob`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch The first version had `\everyjob\expandafter{\directlua{...}}`, that's why I asked. Maybe showing how `\strcmp` could be defined would be useful.

Comment: @JosephWright: this is the correct answer.